# Como definir um valor padrão para parâmetros em JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Boa tarde!

Não vou entrar em um contexto de sistema, pra não alongar, mas, vamos supor o código abaixo:

```js
let meuNome = "Lucas"
function setNome(meuNome) {
    return meuNome;
}
```

Como podem ver, quero que minha variável vá direto no parâmetro, só que assim não vai dar certo por motivos óbvios. Como eu devo tratar esse caso então?

Obrigado!

## EDIT

Como definir um valor padrão para parâmetros em JavaScript

Comment: O que exatamente você quer fazer? Quer definir um valor padrão para o parâmetro?

Comment: Isso, Anderson. Em PHP Eu consigo, em JS não sei como funciona.

Comment: Valeu! Vou ler, muito obrigado por saber "perguntar" por mim rs.